# How to change the temp path used by the CLI for uploading app files in cf push

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-cli

While deploying apps via `cf push` the CF CLI stores app files locally in a temporary path for uploading. The CF CLI uses default temp file location such as `/tmp` (on Unix).

We would like to change the location, is it possible to configure the CLI to use a different temp location?

Comment: Why do you want to change the location?

Comment: We want to change it because our default /tmp filesystems are rather small so we sometimes run out of space that blocks deployment automation. We want to switch to FS location with bigger disk size and monitoring in place to mitigate that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `export TMPDIR=/tmp/newtmpdir`.